# Microsoft graph query: is user member of group?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

A react application queries the Microsoft Graph to discover if a user is a member of a particular active directory group. Right now, there's this route:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
```

The above does work in the application. It returns a (fairly sizable) object containing all of the user's groups, so I *could* iterate through the list, but it would be nice to directly check if the user is a member of a *single* group.

Given that I can already see the list of all groups, this doesn't seem like it should be difficult, but I'm not finding the route to do so.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

P.S. It would be nice if I could do this without requiring administrator permission on the application registration.

Answer (score 10):

If you already know the group's ID, you can get the members of that group, and check whether the user is a member. I.e. the inverse of what you are doing now.

Or, if you have both the user's and the group's ID, you can filter like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038/memberOf?$filter=id eq '1e770bc2-3c5f-487f-871f-16fbdf1c8ed8'`

The first ID is the user, and the filter's ID is the group.

If it is for the currently signed in user, you can shorten it to

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$filter=id eq '1e770bc2-3c5f-487f-871f-16fbdf1c8ed8'`.

If the user isn't a member of the given group, you will get a return code `Request_ResourceNotFound`

Comment: On this case, $filter is not supported. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: It is supported, adding header ConsistencyLevel=eventual and param $count=true, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-headers).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of the group, you can combine `$count` URL segment together with `$filter` query parameter

```
GET /v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/$count?$filter=id eq '{userId}'
```

The result will either `1` or `0`. `1` means that a user is a member of the group, `0` means that a user is not a member.

The request requires `ConsistencyLevel=eventual` header.